# Django Admin Error - unbalanced parenthesis

Tags: python, regex, django

When I point my browser to localhost:8000/admin, I get

> error at /admin/
>
> unbalanced parenthesis

The code that produces this error:

Project - urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^host/', include('host.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

Host (app) - urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('host.views',
    url(r'^all/$', 'EventsAll'),
    url(r'^get/(?P<event_id>\d+)/$)', 'Event'),
)
```

However, if I disable

```
url(r'^get/(?P<event_id>\d+)/$)', 'Event'),
```

the admin console works perfectly. Is the regex somehow interfering with the parenthesis?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have one open parenthesis and two close parenthesis in that regular expression.  I'd remove the one after the $.

Comment: I was trying to solve this and ended up reading numerous posts about python and escaping special characters in regex, I've been sitting here too long! Thanks Mike!

Comment: I've done that a hundred times it seems - looked for the complicated when the problem was simple.  Glad to help!